# Django DRF how to use to_representation and to_internal_value?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) is very brief, and I'm unable to figure out how to use it from reading the [source code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L417).

Here is what I want to accomplish in pseudocode:

```
def transform_result(self, data):
    ret = {}
    for entry in data:
        type = entry['type']
        if type in ret:
            ret[type].add({entry['id'], entry['tag']})
        else:
            new_type = ret.add(type)
            new_type.add({entry['id'], entry['tag']})
    return ret
```

Which should take this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "Color",
        "tag": "Blue"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "Color",
        "tag": "Red"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "type": "Shape",
        "tag": "Square"
    },
]
```

And transform it to this:

```
[
    {
        "type": "Color",
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "tag": "Blue"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "tag": "Red"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Shape",
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "tag": "Square"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Should this be done using `to_representation` and `to_internal_value`? If so, how could it be done?

Comment: Is this for data coming in that you want to deserialize or data going out that you want to serialize?